# Javascript two dimensional array initialization

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-2-dimension

Meet with a really weird javascript problem. See my codes below:

```
function initBadScripts(controlArray) {
    var scriptsLine = prompt("Please enter the bad scripts", "debug");

    if (scriptsLine != null) {
        var pattern = /;/;
        var nameList = scriptsLine.split(pattern);
        alert(nameList+" "+nameList.length);
        for(var counter = 0; counter < nameList.length; counter++){
           controlArray[counter][0]=true;
           controlArray[counter][1]= new RegExp(nameList[counter],"g");
           alert(controlArray[counter][0]);
        }
    }
    alert("wtf!");
}

var controlArray = [[]];
initBadScripts(controlArray);
```

I defined a function, and call that function. A 2-dimensional array called 'controlArray' is defined with no value. Basically, the function check the user's input and use regular expression to make a 'namelist'. For example, if the user type in

```
ExampleOne;ExampleTwo
```

The function will create an array called 'nameList'

```
nameList=[ExampleOne,ExampleTwo];
```

Then I want to make a dynamical initialization of the 2-dimensional array called 'controlArray', according to the length of nameList. However this only works fine the nameList'length is 1. If it exceeds one (the user type in 'ExampleOne;ExampleTwo'), the ExampleTwo does not go into the array, and the

```
alert("wtf");
```

doesn't run at all. This seems that there is already an error before it. Any comments?

Comment: Use your dev tools & debugger to find the error.

Comment: Sorry I am writing an grease monkey scripts, which can not be usually debugged.

Comment: `var pattern = /;/;` should probably be `var pattern = /;/g;` or else it will only pick up first `;` in input resulting in an array of max size 2

Comment: That's not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have a true 2-dimensional array.  Rather, you're putting a second array inside the first array.  Change it to this:

```
...
for(var counter = 0; counter < nameList.length; counter++){
       controlArray[counter] = [true, new RegExp(nameList[counter],"g")];
...
```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks a lot. By the way, what do you mean that I am putting a second array inside the first array?

Comment: If we coded it differently, you could fill it like this: `var child1 = [true,/abc/g]; var child2 = [true,/def/g]; var controlArray = [child1, child2];` You have nested the child arrays into the parent array. This controlArray and the controlArray above would be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Yes or you declare your variable like that:

```
var controlArray = [[],[]];
```

or

```
var controlArray = new Array(2);
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  controlArray[i] = new Array(2);
}
```